Phonebook (working with vCard file)
Project dependencies:

vobject
prettytable
python-dotenv

Environment variable (.env):
VCF=contacts.vcf

The file to be read is specified via an environment variable; the contacts are processed (vCard parsing occurs) and saved as a human-readable table.
General recommendations on the code are welcome, I am especially concerned about the correctness of working with the date (determining age, zodiac sign). How correctly is this done?
My code:
import os
import vobject
from datetime import date
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from prettytable import PrettyTable

load_dotenv()
v_card = os.getenv('VCF')

vcf_table = PrettyTable()
vcf_table.field_names = [
    'full_name',
    'birthday_and_years',
    'address',
    'number'
]

vcf_table.align = 'l'
vcf_table.sortby = 'full_name'
vcf_table.hrules = True

with open(v_card) as phone_book:
    # allowQP to process quoted-printable data
    contacts = vobject.readComponents(phone_book, allowQP=True)
    for contact in contacts:
        # Name, patronymic and surname
        full_name = contact.fn.value

        # If a contact has a birthday, we display it in Russian format
        # Using the difference between the current date and the day of birth, we determine the age
        # For fun, we determine the zodiac sign
        # We handle the exception if this field does not exist
        try:
            birthday = date.fromisoformat(contact.bday.value)
            today = date.today()
            years = (today - birthday).days // 365

            zodiac_signs = {
                'Capricorn': (date(birthday.year, month=12, day=22), date(birthday.year, month=1, day=19)),
                'Aquarius': (date(birthday.year, month=1, day=20), date(birthday.year, month=2, day=18)),
                'Pisces': (date(birthday.year, month=2, day=19), date(birthday.year, month=3, day=20)),
                'Aries': (date(birthday.year, month=3, day=21), date(birthday.year, month=4, day=19)),
                'Taurus': (date(birthday.year, month=4, day=20), date(birthday.year, month=5, day=20)),
                'Gemini': (date(birthday.year, month=5, day=21), date(birthday.year, month=6, day=20)),
                'Cancer': (date(birthday.year, month=6, day=21), date(birthday.year, month=7, day=22)),
                'Leo': (date(birthday.year, month=7, day=23), date(birthday.year, month=8, day=22)),
                'Virgo': (date(birthday.year, month=8, day=23), date(birthday.year, month=9, day=22)),
                'Libra': (date(birthday.year, month=9, day=23), date(birthday.year, month=10, day=22)),
                'Scorpio': (date(birthday.year, month=10, day=23), date(birthday.year, month=11, day=21)),
                'Sagittarius': (date(birthday.year, month=11, day=22), date(birthday.year, month=12, day=21))
            }

            for sign, (start_date, end_date) in zodiac_signs.items():
                if start_date <= birthday <= end_date:
                    birthday_and_years = f'Birthday: {birthday.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}\nZodiac signs: {sign}\nAge: {years}'

        except AttributeError:
            birthday_and_years = ''

        # There may be several phone numbers, we display them all
        number = []
        for phone_number in contact.tel_list:
            number.append(phone_number.value)
        number = '\n'.join(number)

        # If there is a comma in the address (for example: Lenin 1, apt. 2) - it is considered a list
        # If there are no commas - a line
        # We handle the exception if the field does not exist
        address = []
        try:
            for adds in contact.adr_list:
                street = adds.value.street
                if isinstance(street, str):
                    address.append(street)
                else:
                    address.append(''.join(street))
            address = '\n'.join(address)
        except AttributeError:
            address = ''

        # Filling in the table
        vcf_table.add_row(
            [
                full_name,
                birthday_and_years,
                address,
                number,
            ]
        )

# Table header indicating the number of records
vcf_table.title = f'rowcount: {vcf_table.__getattr__("rowcount")}'

# Write to file with current date
with open(f'{v_card}_{today}.txt', 'w') as report:
    report.write(vcf_table.get_string())


Would this not fail for "Capricorn" every time? The start date is set to 22-Dec of the birth year (so way at the end) and the end date is 19-Jan of the same year (near the beginning). So the code checking for "start date <= birthday <= end date" will not return true as start date is higher than end date. Or does this chaining work?

@htmlcoderexe Yes, it seems to have problems for some dates. For example, for 1987-01-19, 1987-12-22 - the zodiac sign was not determined. Thanks for pointing this out. This solution was suggested to me by ChatGPT, everything else I came across on the Internet was built on terrible if - a bunch of lines of poorly readable code. I'm a little lost, as I don't know how to fix this. If you have any advice, I'd be glad to hear it.

I am sure there is some specific way to do this easily that I cannot think of right now, but the two less-nice-but-working ways would be 1) have Capricorn in there twice, for 1-Jan to 19-Jan and 22-Dec to 31-Dec and 2) remove Capricorn from the list entirely and set is as default (set birthday_and_years to the string corresponding to Capricorn, which would then get overwritten in the for statement if the date matches any of the other 11 zodiacs

Documentation
You should add a docstring at the top of the code to:

Summarize its purpose
Emphasize it relies on an environment variable
State the format of the required input file with a reference to documentation
Describe the typical output

For example, start with what you posted in your question text:
"""
The file to be read is specified via an environment variable
the contacts are processed (vCard parsing occurs) and saved as a human-readable table.

"""

Environment
The code could check if the VCF environment variable exists.  For example,
I do not have it set in my environment.  If it is not set, you could display a verbose message instructing the user to set the environment variable to point to an existing vCard file
Also, consider a more unique and descriptive name for the variable.  Short names like
VCF are more likely to be taken already.  Perhaps VCARD_FILE is more apt.
Leap year
Check to make sure the code handles leap years correctly.  I see 365.
Layout
The following would be easier to understand with better alignment:
'Capricorn': (date(birthday.year, month=12, day=22), date(birthday.year, month=1, day=19)),
'Aquarius': (date(birthday.year, month=1, day=20), date(birthday.year, month=2, day=18)),
'Pisces': (date(birthday.year, month=2, day=19), date(birthday.year, month=3, day=20)),

Like this:
'Capricorn'     : (date(birthday.year, month=12, day=22), date(birthday.year, month=1 , day=19)),
'Aquarius'      : (date(birthday.year, month=1 , day=20), date(birthday.year, month=2 , day=18)),
'Pisces'        : (date(birthday.year, month=2 , day=19), date(birthday.year, month=3 , day=20)),
'Aries'         : (date(birthday.year, month=3 , day=21), date(birthday.year, month=4 , day=19)),
'Taurus'        : (date(birthday.year, month=4 , day=20), date(birthday.year, month=5 , day=20)),
'Gemini'        : (date(birthday.year, month=5 , day=21), date(birthday.year, month=6 , day=20)),
'Cancer'        : (date(birthday.year, month=6 , day=21), date(birthday.year, month=7 , day=22)),
'Leo'           : (date(birthday.year, month=7 , day=23), date(birthday.year, month=8 , day=22)),
'Virgo'         : (date(birthday.year, month=8 , day=23), date(birthday.year, month=9 , day=22)),
'Libra'         : (date(birthday.year, month=9 , day=23), date(birthday.year, month=10, day=22)),
'Scorpio'       : (date(birthday.year, month=10, day=23), date(birthday.year, month=11, day=21)),
'Sagittarius'   : (date(birthday.year, month=11, day=22), date(birthday.year, month=12, day=21))


Thank you for taking the time to look at my humble code. Can you please tell me what is a good practice for handling a missing environment variable? Should I additionally handle cases where the variable is specified but its value is missing or the value refers to a missing file? I thought about these edge cases and considered their handling redundant, since the standard exceptions that occur in this case provide the necessary information to find and fix the path to the file

@ykoavlil: You're welcome.  I don't have anything specific in mind.  If you are satisfied with the standard exceptions, that is fine.  Or, you could display a more verbose message  instructing the user to set the environment variable to point to an existing vcard file.  Answer updated.
